# Preserving line breaks in VSCode Java formatter

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, format

I am currently using **`Java`** in **`Visual Studio Code`**, and I am having a problem with formatting.

I want to preserve the line breaks I made on purpose even after formatting.

**BUT** **`VSCode`** doesn't allows me to do that.

Is there a solution for this problem?

***[Before formatting]***

```
someClass.someMethod(
        veryLongParameterOne,
        veryLongParameteTwo,
        veryLongParameterThree
);
```

***[After formatting]***

```
someClass.someMethod(
        veryLongParameterOne,
        veryLongParameteTwo,
        veryLongParameterThree);
```

All I want is to keep the code the same before and after formatting.

Comment: VS Code [Language Support for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) which is based on Eclipse does not provide an UI for the Java formatter settings, but Eclipse does it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use some special comment to let the extension skip format in a range:

```java
//@formatter:off
someClass.someMethod(
        veryLongParameterOne,
        veryLongParameteTwo,
        veryLongParameterThree
);
//@formatter:on
```

2. Or you can trigger a command `Java: Open Java Formatter Settings with Preview` to view some basic format settings in UI. Meanwhile it will generate a .xml format profile in .vscode folder, in which you can find all format settings there.

Answer (score 0):

In your format settings (e.g. eclipse-java-google-style.xml) use this:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.join_wrapped_lines" value="false"/>
```